# Unable to pass PHP string to jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a script on my system that provide list of active interfaces -

```
 $ interfaces
 eth0
 lo
 wlan0
```

Now Here is my PHP Code -

```
 <?php
 $output=shell_exec('./interfaces');
 $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $output));
 $string = str_replace("\0","",$string);
 $data = preg_split('/\s+/',$string);  // There was a typo here, changed $output to  
                                        //  $string 
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

There goes my jquery -

```
    $.getJSON('nw/sample1.php', function(data) {

    $(data).each(function(i,item) {

            alert(item);

    });

    });
```

I expect there should be `3` alert box visible each highlighting one of the active interface.

For e.g., 1st alert box should say `"eth0"`, second say `"lo"` and so on but it is not woking as expected.

I do new to all this so clear me where am I getting it wrong ??

Thanks

**Edit :**

**Output of sample1.php in browser**

```
 ["eth0","lo","wlan0"]
```

**$.each(data, ...) and $data.each ... ** both behaves in same fashion.

**console.log(data) output**
[image]

Comment: Which part is not working as expected? What output do you receive and how is it incorrect?

Comment: If you visit the page in your browser, what does the json_encoded string look like?

Comment: Did you try to `console.log` your `data` ???

Comment: Why process `$output` into `$string` but then not use `$string`?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) converts the echoed string returned by `json_encode` to a JavaScript object after receiving the data, indicated by the examples on the linked doc page. Those do, however, use `$.each(data, function(key, val){ ... })` instead of `$(data).each(...)`, which may be the problem here.

Comment: @ajp15243, agreed. I already deleted my second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is just the nw/sample1.php

I used a 'normal' string in sample1.php, and the $getJSON worked like a charm, so I'll focus how you retrieve the data stored in 'interfaces' file. Just check jQuery JSON is working by substituting the code in sample1.php with this:

```
<?php
$string = 'eth0 lo wlan0';
$string = str_replace("\0","",$string);
$data = preg_split('/\s+/',$string);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `json_encode($data)` to notify the client - `parse it as json instead of text/HTML`

So,

```
<?php
 $output=shell_exec('./interfaces');
 $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $output));
 $string = str_replace("\0","",$string);
 $data = preg_split('/\s+/',$string);  // There was a typo here, changed $output to  
                                        //  $string 

 header('Content-Type: application/json'); // ## ADDED this line ##
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Now, your `javascript/jquery` should be able to do - what you expect it to do !

Please try and revert back !